# Chilli plant help

Tags: chili

[image]

Hi

I’ve had this chilli plant for about one year.  Only one part of the Y has flowered and grown chillies.  It seems all the energy went into producing the chillies and this part of the plant lost all its leaves and looks almost dead.

I’ve replanted and given the plant some food (I think I over watered) and this is the reason for the yellow leaves.

As you can see the Y part of the plant that did not produce chillies originally has had a pert while the other part has only one small
growth.

Is there anything I can do now to create a fuller/bushier plant or should I start over.   Any feedback on leaves etc would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Was the plant outdoor? [in that case, it has hit cold weather, just wait] Is the windows insulated? Did it receive enough sunlight? Note: many people doesn't keep such plants for more than one year [let some chilli pepper in the ground]. Sometime also insect will cause similar damages [caterpillars in fall season]

Comment: Does that bucket have holes for drainage? If not, saturated soil could give you all kinds of trouble. But it looks like it doesn't get an optimal amount of light. If overwintering you can let it be, but then cut it back 20-30% in the spring when you transition it outside. Watch for aphids - I always get aphids overwintering peppers indoors.